# Programmatically control brush and pass relevant information

Tags: javascript, d3.js

this is an extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58468426/can-d3-brushevent-return-the-activated-brush) question from yesterday. I am attempting to draw and create multiple brushes. The bruteforce method i am using does ok, but i need additional functionality to programmatically control each of these newly created brushes,

```
    createBrush(){
        //Brushes
        var brushGroups = []
        for(var i=0; i<this.uniqueCats.length; i++){
            //BRUSH CONTAINER
            brushGroups[i] = d3.select('#brushContainer')
                .append('g')
                .attr('id',`${this.uniqueCats[i]}brush`)
                .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left},0)`)
                .attr('class','brush');

            //BRUSH
            var brushID = this.uniqueCats[i]
            this[`${this.uniqueCats[i]}Brush`] = d3.brushX()
                .extent([[0, (i*135)+38], [this.width,(i*135)+170]])
                .on('end',(i)=>{
                    console.log('hi')
                    this.updateBubbles(i)
                })

            //CALL BRUSH from the brush container
            brushGroups[i].call(this[`${this.uniqueCats[i]}Brush`])
        }
    }
```

As you can see above I 1) create a brush container 2) create a brush, 3) call that brush from the container. The main issue i am having it passing relevant information to the `on` for `this.updateBubbles()`. The hope was for each brush to pass in specific information to `updatebubbles()` that would allow me to understand which brush was being activated.

From there I decided to use the more elegant d3 approach with `enter()` but, this method fails to invoke a brush at all,

```
    createBrushv2(){var that =this
        var brushContainer = d3.select('#brushContainer')
            .selectAll('g')
            .data(this.uniqueCats)

        var brushContainerEnter = brushContainer
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('id', d=> `${d}brush`)

        brushContainer = brushContainerEnter.merge(brushContainer)
            .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left},0)`)
            .attr('class','brush')
            .each( function(d,i){
                console.log(i)
                d3.brushX()
                    .extent([[0,(i*135)+38], [that.width,(i*135)+170]])
                    .on('end',that.updateBubbles(d))
            })

    }
```

The `updateBubbles()` function is whats evoked from each brush, so this function needs to be able to understand which brush is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code, which makes your question *too broad*. Therefore, I'll only deal with the issue of the brush not being invoked.

Before anything else, congratulations for moving from approach #1 (`for` loop) to approach #2 (D3 selections). In a D3 code, it's almost a very bad idea using loops to append anything.

That being said, unlike your first snippet, you're not actually calling the brush in the second one.

Therefore, this...

```
d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0,(i*135)+38], [that.width,(i*135)+170]])
    .on('end',that.updateBubbles(d))
```

Should be:

```
d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0,(i*135)+38], [that.width,(i*135)+170]])
    .on('end', that.updateBubbles)(d3.select(this))
```

Even better, you should use a `selection.call`, just like in your first approach. Also, have in mind that `that.updateBubbles(d)` will invoke the function immediately, and that's not what you want.

Here is a very basic snippet as a demo:

```js
const data = d3.range(5);

const svg = d3.select("svg");

createBrushv2();

function createBrushv2() {
  var brushContainer = svg.selectAll(".brush")
    .data(data)

  var brushContainerEnter = brushContainer.enter()
    .append('g');

  brushContainer = brushContainerEnter.merge(brushContainer)
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
      return "translate(0," + (d * 25) + ")"
    })
    .attr('class', 'brush')
    .each(function(d) {
      d3.brushX()
        .extent([
          [0, 0],
          [300, 20]
        ])
        .on('end', updateBubbles)(d3.select(this))
    })
    .each(function() {
      d3.brushX().move(d3.select(this), [0, 300])
    })
};

function updateBubbles(brush) {
  console.log(brush)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. It is a surprising perplexing solution. I am working within a class structure. So what then becomes my problem is the abolishment of my former this by the brush which is now this. Within the updatebubbles().

I appreciate the thoughtful answer.

Comment: Could expand on why call should be used? I've tried to implement this and cannot seem to get this to work

Comment: It's just more idiomatic and convenient.

Comment: @MadmanLee please do not edit my answer. My answer explains exactly the issue I mentioned (*"I'll only deal with the issue of the brush not being invoked"*). If you have a secondary issue with `this` because the use of classes, feel free to write your own answer.